# Kentico 11 - Admin portal styling broken

Tags: kentico, kentico-11

Has anyone experienced a situation in Kentico where the admin portal is broken? I've attached an image where you can see the styling is completely missing.[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in Kentico Event Log or JS errors in browser console?

Comment: Hi Dmitry. No js errors in console but I am getting 404 errors for the stylehsheets, which is the main issue, and that matches up with even log errors:


Source: Application_Error

Event code: PAGENOTFOUND

Event URL: /cms/getdoc/sdfsdf-sdfsd-fsd-fsdfsdf/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?stylesheetfile=/App_Themes/Default/DesignMode.css

Answer (score 3):

Typically an issue with 1 or many of the following:

- In general, installation failed
- No permissions granted to the IIS_IUSRS to the directory in the file system
- The directory/file does not exist in the file system
- Macros need to be resigned due to a change to the CMSHashStringSalt key in the web.config
- Improper website set up/configuration in IIS
- Caching

**UPDATE**

Remembered a few other things:

- Check the /App_Themes director and make sure you have the following themes

  - Design
  - Default
  - Global

It may be best to copy those three themes from another installation with the same version and hotfix.

Comment: Thanks Brendon. Looks like it may be an issue with the instance of Kentico we're working with.